# When will object be disposed if created only for parameter to function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

Compare:

```
Using Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
        strWebResponse = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Using
End Using
```

with:

```
Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = new XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream)
```

In the first example, `Response` is obviously disposed at the second `End Using` statement.

In the second example, when will the `WebResponse` object created by `Request.GetResponse()` be disposed?

Should the second example be rewritten as follows to ensure the `WebResponse` is properly disposed?

```
Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = new XmlDocument
Using Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse
    xmldoc.Load(Response.GetResponseStream)
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the second example, when will the WebResponse object created by Request.GetResponse() be disposed?

No. You're not calling `Dispose` explicitly, and it's not a resource within a `Using` statement, so it won't get disposed.

It will eventually get garbage collected, but you shouldn't rely on the timing of that - you should dispose it directly. In particular, with `WebResponse`, there's a pool of connections with a maximum number per target - so if you try to fetch multiple pages from the same server without disposing of the response, you can end up hanging while you wait for an earlier response to be finalized.

Comment: See my edit - would you advise the code be written that way instead?

Comment: @CJ7: Assuming you need to use WebRequest at all, yes.

Comment: How could I not use `WebRequest` in this scenario?

Comment: @CJ7: Use `XDocument.Load(uri)` instead. That doesn't help if you need to add custom headers etc, of course.